# Read Pcap file in C# GUI

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am building a GUI in C# which allows me to upload a file and see its contents it works with a plain text file. When I try to insert a `Pcap` file I get an obscure character and that's it(I added the references of Pcap.net Dll files in Visual-studio). The purpose of the software is to get/upload a `Pcap` file and that I can filter by IP address for example. I checked the option of pcap.net but I still can not get what I want. I saw that it is possible to convert between a `Pcap` file to a CSV file but this could create a problem on another computer that will try to run the program.

I'm learning from this site: https://github.com/PcapDotNet/Pcap.Net/wiki/Pcap.Net-Tutorial-Obtaining-the-device-list

I did not understand how or where I put this code.

Load file in `richTextBox`.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
        string filename = openFileDialog1.FileName;
        string readfile = File.ReadAllText(filename);
        richTextBox1.Text = readfile;
    }
```

Comment: Even though you have added Pcap.NET as a reference, you are not using it. Instead, you open the binary PCAP file as a text file. Please study the documentation and tutorials. Most likely you want to open a PCAP file (instead of a live network interface) and then filter the traffic.

Comment: I can not implement the options of pcap.net within the וֹ of the software.@Codo

Comment: What do you mean "within the i of the software"? Did you look at the documentation and tutorials? Actually try to follow them like Codo suggested? What you've shown us suggests you haven't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am building a GUI in C# which allows me to upload a file and see its contents it works with a plain text file.

That's not sufficient to have it work with pcap files, as pcap files (like a number of other different types of file) are *not* plain text.

> The purpose of the software is to get/upload a Pcap file and that I can filter by IP address for example.

That's very different from a file that works with plain text files; you'll need to handle the format of a pcap file.  To do that from C#, Pcap.Net is exactly what you want.

See ["Handling offline dump files"](https://github.com/PcapDotNet/Pcap.Net/wiki/Pcap.Net-Tutorial-Handling-offline-dump-files) in the Pcap.Net tutorial for information on how to open a pcap file and read from it.  See ["Interpreting the packets"](https://github.com/PcapDotNet/Pcap.Net/wiki/Pcap.Net-Tutorial-Interpreting-the-packets#interpreting-the-packets) for information on how to get packet details from a packet read from the file.